# Looking for books written from perspective of a magazine photoeditor or art director

Tags: photo-editing, books

Can anyone recommend a book written by a magazine editor, maybe a memoir, describing the interactions while working with professional photographers or photojournalists ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you any work of John Hedgecoe (not their manuals, their memories, criticism, etc)
http://www.amazon.com/John-Hedgecoe/e/B000AQTS4S

or

http://www.alibris.com/booksearch?qsort=&page=2&matches=107&author=John+Hedgecoe&browse=1&aid=2148670